# How to do typedef of any function in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, typedef, pointer-to-member

I think i want something impossible, but at least i can ask ))

We can typedef a pointer of function, which gets nothing and returns nothing like this.

```
typedef void (*fpointer)();
```

If function gets an int, then

```
typedef void (*fpointer)(int);
```

So i want to know, can i typedef a pointer of any function? (non class member)

Thanks to all.

EDIT:

```
    template <typename T>
    struct IsMemberFunctionPointerRaw
    {enum{result = 0};};

    template <typename T, typename S>
    struct IsMemberFunctionPointerRaw<T (S::*)()> 
    {enum {result = 1};};
```

...........................................

```
    template <typename T, typename S, 
        typename P01, typename P02, typename P03, typename P04, typename P05,
        typename P06, typename P07, typename P08, typename P09, typename P10,
        typename P11, typename P12, typename P13, typename P14, typename P15,
        typename P16, typename P17, typename P18, typename P19, typename P20>
    struct IsMemberFunctionPointerRaw<T (S::*)(
        P01, P02, P03, P04, P05, 
        P06, P07, P08, P09, P10, 
        P11, P12, P13, P14, P15,
        P16, P17, P18, P19, P20)> 
    {enum {result = 1};};
```

This is from Loki library. There are 20 structs for every fucntion. Just i thought it's too bad style, and it was interesting to find better solution.

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to define a function pointer type for any given function, or are you asking if it is possible to define a function pointer that would work with any function?

Comment: Loki seems to still strive for compatibility with pre-var-arg-templates code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no type in C++ that is a supertype of all function types. How would you call it except by casting back to a function type whose parameter and return types you know?

You can however store any function pointer or functor in the [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) type, as long as they have the same signature:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

// Actual function
int add1(int x) { return x + 1; }

// Functor (callable object)
struct Add {
  Add(int y) : y(y) {}
  int operator()(int x) { return x + y; }
  int y;
};

int main() {

  std::function<int(int)> g = add1;
  std::cout << g(2) << '\n';

  g = Add(2);
  std::cout << g(3) << '\n';

  int z = 3;
  g = [z](int x) { return x + z; };
  std::cout << g(4) << '\n';

}
```

This is one way to pass C++11 lambdas to functions, agnostic of their actual (implementation-defined) type.

There is another option: you can unsafely cast any function pointer `p` to another function type using `reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(p)`. However, you must cast it back to its original type before calling it. Technically you cannot simply use `reinterpret_cast<void*>(p)` because object-pointer types and function-pointer types are not guaranteed to have the same size, though in practice they are the same on all common architectures.

If you simply want a trait to determine whether a given function pointer type is a member function pointer, then you can use variadic templates to match any number of argument types:

```
template<typename T>
struct IsMemberFunctionPointerRaw {
  enum { value = 0 };
};

template<typename Result, typename Class, typename... Args>
struct IsMemberFunctionPointerRaw<Result (Class::*)(Args...)> {
  enum { value = 1 };
};
```

This is codified in C++11 as [`std::is_member_function_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer).

Comment: It was about pointers. How would you call it, except... Somehow, that doesn't bother me for data-pointers with `void*`, at all.

Comment: You know, µC are quite common, even more than smartphones, desktops and server (including mainframes) together. And it is not uncommon for them to have different-sized data and code pointers. `std::is_member_function_pointer`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about variadic templates.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to `typedef` the function pointers on your example to `fpointer`, you would use (respectively):

```
typedef void (*fpointer) ();

typedef void (*fpointer) (int);
```

Comment: You can't do that, moreover, what would it achieve?  What arguments would you call that function pointer with?  What would it return?

Answer (score -1):

```
typedef int (*MyPointerType)(int,float);
MyPointerType ptr = nullptr; // MyPointerType just works as a type!
```

Answer (score -1):

`void*` is such a universal pointer. void* variables can hold pointers on anything including free functions. But there is no such thing as abstract function in C so there is no pointer to it.

In the same way as there is no abstract integer type that will cover byte, short and int. And so there is no such thing as "pointer to any integer" in C.

Comment: It's a common extension, but `void*` need not be compatible with function pointers at all.

Comment: @Deduplicator Probably, but without such compatibility you cannot implement fundamental things like `dlsym()` http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html

Comment: So? Not all the world is Unixoid. Anyway, there are ports to such architecture AFAICT, and they just use two different functions, one for data, one for code.